# Python store variable with two columns into table created with SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, store

I created a variable that stores patient ID and a count of the number of missed appointments per patient. I created a table with SQLite and I am trying to store my variable into my created table but I am getting an error of "ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type". Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('STORE')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PatientNoShow")
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PatientNoShow ("PatientId" text, "No-show" text)""")

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\missedappointments.csv")
df2 = df[df['No-show']=="Yes"]
pt_counts = df2["PatientId"].value_counts()

c.executemany("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO PatientNoShow VALUES (?, ?)", pt_counts)
```

Thank you in advance for any help! Still learning, so any kind of "explain to me like I'm 5" answers will be appreciated! Also, once I create my tables and store info in them, how would I print or get a visual of the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote that the two variables are of type text in

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PatientNoShow ("PatientId" text, "No-show" text)""")
```

but `pt_counts` contains integers because it counts the values in the column `PatientId`, besides `.executemany()` needs a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) to work properly.

This piece of code should work if `PatientId` is of string type:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('STORE')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PatientNoShow")
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PatientNoShow ("PatientId" text, "No-show" integer)""") # type changed

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:/Users/bob/Desktop/Trasporti_project/Matchings_locations/norm_data/standard_locations.csv")
pt_counts = df["standard_name"].value_counts()

c.executemany("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO PatientNoShow VALUES (?, ?)", pt_counts.iteritems()) # this is a sequence
```